# Unable to connect to a client server

Tags: vimrc, clientserver, wsl

### Description

Vim does not connect to a clientserver, which causes issues using VimTex and zathura. Upon opening any file in an Ubuntu terminal, the following error is displayed:

```
Error detected while processing /root/.vimrc:
line   21:
E240: No connection to the X server
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

### Steps to Reproduce

This is my .vimrc file:

```
  1 filetype on
  2 filetype plugin on
  3 filetype indent on
  4 syntax enable
  5
  6 call plug#begin()
  7 Plug 'lervag/vimtex'
  8 Plug 'preservim/nerdtree'
  9 call plug#end()
 10
 11 set nocompatible
 12 set number
 13 set tabstop=4
 14 set laststatus=2
 15
 16 let g:vimtex_view_method = 'zathura'
 17 let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode = 0
 18 let g:vimtex_compiler_method = 'latexmk'
 19
 20 if empty(v:servername) && exists('*remote_startserver')
 21   call remote_startserver('VIM')
 22 endif
```

From here, open any file in the terminal, with commands such as

```
vim .vimrc
```

or

```
vim text.tex
```

and the error message from above will appear.

### System Info

I use Ubuntu as available in the Windows Store of Windows 11 Pro. Here is the system info prompted from Vim:

```
  1 System info:
  2   OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
  3   Vim version: VIM 8.2 (1-3995, 4563, 4646, 4774, 4895, 4899, 4901, 4919)
  4   Has clientserver: true
  5   Servername: undefined (vim started without --servername)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I understand that you are using WSL which only allow to use console application by default. Did you do something to address that limitation? Without X server I suppose Zathura can't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**: Following Vivian De Smedt's comment, I realized I hadn't addressed such a limitation of WSL. I followed the instructions on [this article](https://medium.com/javarevisited/using-wsl-2-with-x-server-linux-on-windows-a372263533c3) from Medium entitled "Using WSL-2 with X-server — Linux on Window" and can now connect to the X-Server.

Thank you so much! I'm quite new to Vim and found this very helpful.

EDIT: In case of link rot:

1. I installed [VcXsrv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/), then in the properties -> shortcut -> target, I entered `"C:\Program Files\VcXsrv\vcxsrv.exe" :0 -ac -terminate -lesspointer -multiwindow -clipboard -wgl -dpi auto`
2. I entered `netstat -abno|findstr 6000` into Windows Powershell
3. I installed terminator with `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install terminator`,
4. I validated terminator by entering `DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0 terminator &` into Ubuntu
5. I allowed VcXsrv all connections in Windows Firewall
6. I added this to my .bashrc file: `export DISPLAY=$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{print $2}'):0`
7. I started VcXsrv with access control disabled.

Afterwards, Vim could connect to the X-Server.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-)

Comment: Please [edit] to include instructions from the link directly (with source attribution) so that the answer stands alone in case of link rot.

Comment: Maybe could you accept your answer using the v button ne t to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

You must run GUI version only, i.e. `gvim` or `vim -g`. It should work under WSL, assuming you have W11 with up-to-date WSL installation.